# Le nombre grammatical des operations arithmétiques

Tags: pluriel, nombres, mathématiques

La citation ci-après provient de la page 93 de *Schaum's Outline of French Grammar* de Mary Crocker.

> The verb faire (to do, to make) is used in arithmetical operations. The plural font is used for addition, subtraction, and multiplication. The singular **fait** is used for division.

En tant qu'étudiant de mathématiques, cette différence m'intrigue. Y a-t-il une raison (mathématique à la française)? En anglais, toutes ces quatre opérations sont singulières.

Comment: Si tu ne veux pas te faire passer pour un film des années 50, je te conseille d’utiliser le verbe « égaler ».

Comment: Vous devriez prendre l'habitude d'ajouter des exemples à vos questions...

Answer (score 4):

Je ne retiendrais pas la distinction entre les opérations elles-mêmes, mais plutôt leur traduction en langage naturel et son interprétation en termes de sens ou de grammaire.

À la suite de Grevisse, concernant l'accord du verbe *faire* ou *égale* dans les opérations, je distinguerais deux cas : l'un qui suit la règle générale, l'autre commandé par une double figure de style (syllepse tenant compte d'une ellipse, même s'il me semble ici que c'est le sens qui commande la perception d'une ellipse). Jouette (*Dictionnaire d'orthographe et d'expression écrite*, 1993), montre à travers deux exemples qu'il suit cette règle, sans toutefois l'expliquer.

Pour en revenir à Grevisse, *Le Bon Usage* (7<sup>e</sup> éd. rev., 1959, 820 : 8) articule deux citations lexicographiques, l'une de Littré, l'autre du dictionnaire de l'Académie (8<sup>e</sup> éd.) :

> *Deux multiplié par cinq égale dix* (Littré, art. « égaler ».)
>   *Deux et deux font quatre* (Académie, art. « faire ».)

Dans ce cas a lieu un accord de sens, commandé par une ellipse dans le sujet : **[Le nombre] deux** multiplié par cinq *égale* dix. *Deux* n'est pas considéré comme une quantité, un cardinal, mais comme une chose singulière, d'où le sens sous-jacent « le nombre deux ».

> S'il arrive qu'on ait à écrire en toutes lettres le verbe *égaler* (ou
>   qu'on emploie *faire*  ou *donner*) dans l'expression d'une égalité
>   dont le premier membre est une pluralité, on peut laisser ces verbes
>   au singulier : l'accord est alors sylleptique [c'est un accord
>   commandé par le sens] et se fait avec *nombre* ou *cela*, qu'on a dans
>   la pensée :
>
> *Deux multiplié par cinq ÉGALE dix* (Littré, s. v., *égaler*, 2<sup>o</sup>).

En revanche, dans le cas d'un sujet coordonné, la règle habituelle s'applique :

> Si l'on a *et* dans le premier membre ou encore s'il s'agit de nombres
>   concrets, le pluriel paraît préférable :
>
> *Deux et deux FONT quatre* (Ac., s. v., *faire*).

Le cas de la division ne pouvant relever que du premier cas, pas d'accord.
Les contre-exemples paraissent par ailleurs logiques : 
*Vingt-quatre et douze, divisés par deux,* égalent *douze et six.*

Reste que d'autres analyses existent, plus libérales, mais qui ne fourniraient aucune justification, donc aucune réponse à votre question (puisque vous vouliez des explications plus qu'une règle) : ainsi Girodet (*Pièges et difficulté de la langue française*, 1988, art. « faire ») admet pour la multiplication le pluriel comme le singulier, sans explication, mais précise que le pluriel est plus fréquent. (Le cas des autres opérations n'est pas évoqué.)

Answer (score 2):

Littéralement, on a :

> Addition : un et un font deux
>
> Soustraction : trois moins un donnent deux (je ne suis pas certain)
>
> Multiplication : Six fois six font trente-six
>
> Division : Douze divisé par trois donne quatre.

Je crois que l’on utilise le singulier pour les opérations non commutatives, car l’idée sous-jacente serait que la division serait une opération sur le dividende et que le diviseur ne serait qu’un paramètre. Mais si ma théorie est vraie, alors on devrait aussi appliquer la même règle à la soustraction.

Answer (score 2):

Si vous voulez donner une tournure littéraire à l'arithmétique, pensez à cet extrait du Don Juan de Molière:

- Ce que je crois?
- Oui.
- Je crois que deux et deux sont quatre, Sganarelle, et que quatre et quatre sont huit."